# LIKE operator for sequence of Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use  wildcard expression to fetch data related to a sequence of numbers. Can I know how to use a series of numbers inside wildcard expression LIKE [0-10].

here is my query:

```
select grade from table where grade LIKE [1-12]?
```

output: is 1 and 2

I referred to t-SQL book and they talk about LIKE N[1-12]. What's the difference between LIKE [1-12] and N[1-12]?

I can use between 1 and 12 to fetch my data. But I am just curious how to use a wildcard for series of numbers with LIKE operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server, `like` has three wildcards.  Underscore `'_'` represents any single character.  `%` represents zero or more characters.  And square brackets.

The expression between the square brackets represents one single character.  So,

```
x like '[abc]'
```

matches "a", "b", or "c" -- and nothing else.  The following matches any digit:

```
x like '[0123456789]'
```

This, however, starts to get cumbersome to type out.  So, SQL Server offers the shorthand:

```
x like '[0-9]'
```

This just means any character from the range starting with 0 and ending at 9.

You could match any hex character with:

```
x like '[0-9ABCDEF]'
```

So, additional characters are allowed in the range.

When you write

```
x like '[1-12]'
```

You are saying x like the range of characters from 1 to 1, plus the character 2.  This is more easily written as:

```
x like '[12]'
```

In any case, you shouldn't store numeric values as strings, and you shouldn't use `like` on numbers.  It is much better to write:

```
grade between 1 and 12
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and crunchy response, Gordon. That was very easy to digest and thank you again fro the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

But if you already have a column with a sequence of numbers and don't know the size, what I've done was this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Keep_Only_Int (@X VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS BIGINT AS BEGIN
    IF @X IS NULL RETURN NULL
    DECLARE @T AS INT = LEN(@X), @I AS INT = 0, @J AS CHAR(1), @RET AS VARCHAR(50) = ''
    WHILE @I < @T BEGIN
        SET @I += 1
        SET @J = SUBSTRING(@X, @I, 1)
        IF ASCII(@J) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 --Numbers, is needed because ¹, ² and ³ are going to return true in the link
            SET @RET += @J
    END
    
    IF LEN(@RET) > 19 RETURN NULL --Bigger then bigint
    RETURN NULLIF(@RET, '')
END
```

An example of usage:

```
create table #a (content varchar(100))
insert #a values ('My number is 123, whatever')
insert #a values ('My number is 1234, whatever')
insert #a values ('My number is ¹²³4, whatever')                --> Special numbers
insert #a values ('My number is one, whatever')                 --> No number
insert #a values ('My number is 1234567890123456789, whatever')
insert #a values ('My number is 12345678901234567890, whatever')--> This is too big!

select * 
    , dbo.Keep_Only_Int(content)
from #a
```

The function already convert the field to BIGINT, so you can use an between statement

```
select * 
from #a
where dbo.Keep_Only_Int(content) between 1 and 2000
```

It is not focused on a great performance, if you are using a table too big I'd recomend creating a specific code for that